# C# Linq dynamic item property

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

Trying to make a reusable function to skip having the same code all over. The issue is that the key on where I do the match has a different name. Else it's all the same.

This is what I have so far. The issue is here: **item.ITEMGROUP** that is different depending on what is running this function.

```
public List<T> FilterGroupIds<T>(List<T> list, string key, string groupids)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupids))
    {
        string[] groupidList = groupids.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        List<T> grouped = new List<T>();
        foreach (string groupidListItem in groupidList)
        {
            var mylist = list
              .Where(item => **item.ITEMGROUP**.Contains(groupidListItem))
              .ToList();

            grouped.AddRange(mylist);
        }
        list = grouped;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Is there a way to use some kind of dynamic check? Example where I use a string to use as "key" that could be ITEMGROUP or something else.

```
var mylist = list.Where(item => item[key].Contains(groupidListItem)).ToList();
```

Comment: Can´t you make a constraint on `T` for a generic interface where the key HAS allways the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just pass this part `item => item[key].Contains(groupidListItem)` with a delegate:

```
public List<T> FilterGroupIds<T>(List<T> list, string key, string groupids, 
                                 Func<T,bool> condition)
{
   ...
   var mylist = list.Where(condition).ToList();
}
```

with `Func<T,bool> condition = item => **item.ITEMGROUP**.Contains(groupidListItem);`. This way you can reuse the function and pass the filter you need based on the type of `T`.

Also you don't need a foreach for this:

```
return list.Where(item => groupIdList.Any(g => item.ITEMGROUP.Contains(g))
           .ToList();
```

is the same as

```
foreach (string groupidListItem in groupidList)
{
    var mylist = list
       .Where(item => **item.ITEMGROUP**.Contains(groupidListItem))
       .ToList();

    grouped.AddRange(mylist);
}
list = grouped;
return list;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use the function FilterGroupIds<T>(List<T> list, string key, string groupids, 
                                 Func<T,bool> condition). How to write the delegate function. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @roady `Func<ItemClass,bool> myFilter = item => item.Group.Contains(groupIdListItem);` would be valid for example. Anything you would otherwise put in your `Where` in the function, you put it in a `Func<whateverYourClassIs,bool>` and pass it to the function. I could give a better example if you could include one of your classes in your question.

Comment: No connection to the database from home but no compilation errors.

    `string[] groupidList = groupids.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    list = list.Where(item => groupidList.Any(g => item.ITEMGROUPID.Contains(g))).ToList();`